# Cannot connect with SSH to my Ubuntu Server that is behind a router

Tags: server, 20.04, ssh, openssh

I installed Ubuntu  Server 20.04 on my old laptop. When it boots Ubuntu Server starts fine and I can login on it. I installed OpenSSH on it and it is active, running. I allowed port 22 on the ufw and the ufw status shows that traffic on port 22 is allowed. This laptop is connected to a router. When I check `ifconfig` I get an inet: **192.168.XX.XXX**

Now I try to login to the server on my desktop PC, it is connected to the same router. When I try to connect to it using Putty, I get a `Network Error: Connection timed out`, every time. In Putty I try to connect to the IP address **192.168.XX.XXX** and port 22. I've had no luck so far.

I went to the router and port forwarded the port:

Internal address          LAN Port        WAN Port      Protocol
192.168.XX.XXX           22                        22              TCP

It still won't connect to the server. Then I downloaded pfpportchecker to see if my ISP is blocking the port, but it says they are not.

I have also tried to Putty with the default gateway IP (the router's IP) with port 22, but that didn't work either.

My port forwarding:

[image: Picture of my port forwarding]

Comment: Might you be using a VPN on either machine?

Comment: On the Desktop computer when I check adapters for the network.
I have two adapters, one is called Ethernet Intel(R)I211 Gigabit and the other vEthernet Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter, they are both active.
Not sure if that is what you asked for.

Edit: I disabled the vEthernet adapter and only left the Ethernet on, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I asked about a VPN based on what you just said I am going to say you are not. I had this issue with a VPN involved.

Comment: On my router where I port forward, I can only do it on something called a Virtual Server. I click on it and that's where I add the ports I want to forward. Could it be something there?

Comment: I added a picture of my port forwarding on the original post.

Comment: You shouldn't need to port forward on your internal network - port forwarding is usually if you come from the WAN side, and need access into a machine. Can you please list the output of the following commands on the server? `systemctl status sshd.service` and `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep sshd`

Comment: The systemctl status sshd.service shows active(running).
The sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN shows: 
0.0.0.0:22 0.0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
127.0.0.53:53 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
:::22  :::* LISTEN

Comment: In that case, it's a complete mystery you can't connect on port 22 if your putty settings are correct and your machines are on the same subnet.

Comment: I wonder if my laptops ability to connect wirelessly could cause trouble.
Edit: iwconfig says, no wireless extensions - so it can't be that either.

Comment: Are they on the same subnet? You don't need to mask your internal IP addresses, that's rather pointless.

Comment: Found this tool https://www.meridianoutpost.com/resources/etools/network/two-ips-on-same-network.php to find out if my IP's are on the same subet.
Have I understood it right that I should put in my ubuntu-server IP and then my Desktop IP, but what subnet should I put in? 255.255.255.0 as shown in ifconfig (ubuntu-server)? Or 255.255.254.0 (from Desktop ipconfig)?

Comment: I managed to change the subnet of my ubuntu-server to match the one on my Destkop (255.255.254.0), still won't work though.

Comment: Found out my ISP is blocking ports, but that shouldn't matter if I try to connect to my server pc from LAN right? 
Considering that they are on the same network.
ISP blocking incoming ports should only be a problem if someone outside of my LAN network tries to connect to my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port forwarded the wrong IP.
Should be the IP of the computer that I try to reach the server with - and not the ubuntu servers IP.
Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your DNS nameserver is not resolving. You may need to configure your DNS resolv.conf file to your server's DNS. The file is located here /etc/resolv.conf
Find out what your server's DNS is and then put it in your resolv.conf file using this command: sudo nano resolv.conf in your linux terminal or shell.
Your DNS nameserver should be written like this in your resolv.conf file:
nameserver 10.0.80.11
Replace the nameserver address above with your server's DNS nameserver.
You can also ping google nameserver 8.8.8.8 to check if your system is able to recognize IP addresses, urls, or nameservers.
I hope this helps you out. Good luck.